# sql запрос, нужна помощь

Tags: sql

```
id|money|procces|time
1|  5   | true | 2016-02-22 08:15:01
2|  3   | false| 2016-02-22 09:35:17
3|  7   | wait| 2016-02-22 11:23:45
```

Нужно выбрать сумму столбца money где procces true или wait, при  этом если wait то нужно что бы он обязательно был time + 60 сек больше текущего времени

Comment: не могу додумать как реализовать второе условие

Comment: `SELECT SUM(money), DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 60 SECOND) AS time
FROM table
WHERE process = true OR (process = false and time > NOW() + INTERVAL 60 SECONDS)`  ???  или вам `group by process` нужен?

Comment: а разве можно коректно высчитать сумму при group by?

Comment: я имел в виду, что возможно вам нужно высчитать сумму отдельно для true и отдельно для wait....... тогда группировка нужна.....а если вы имели в виду вообще сумму money и без разницы какое поле (исключая false) - то тогда конечно не нужно группировать......вот я и уточняю...а то мало ли что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для MySQL так:

```
select sum(money) from table
 where process='true'
    or (process='wait' and time > now() - interval 60 second)
```

для других СУБД поправьте условие для "текущее время - 60 секунд"